# ListBox ItemTemplate update using ToggleButton and attached Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to implement a `ListBox` with `ToggleButton` when I press then the template of `ListBox` should be updated. The template one will have only icons and one will have both icons and text as shown in the image.

[image: Collapsed ListBox, icons only]  [image: Expanded ListBox, text and icons.]

I have created one attached property for this and binded it to the `ToggleButton` `IsChecked` property inside control template, but this attached property is not updating and my template is not changing.
First time when I load the application it is working.

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryDarkBrush}"/>
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>

   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Padding="0"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          Focusable="false">
                  <StackPanel>
                     <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                     <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding local:IsOpenInfo.IsOpen,Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonstyle}" Foreground="White">
                     </ToggleButton>
                  </StackPanel>
               </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource NavigationDataTemplate}"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="local:IsOpenInfo.IsOpen" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource NavigationDataTemplate1}"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="local:IsOpenInfo.IsOpen" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource NavigationDataTemplate}"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonstyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <iconPacks:PackIconMaterialDesign x:Name="MenuItemIcon" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12" Kind="ArrowBack"/>
               <TextBlock Text="Collapse" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                  <Setter TargetName="MenuItemIcon" Property="Kind" Value="ArrowForward"/>
                  <Setter TargetName="txtBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                  <Setter TargetName="MenuItemIcon" Property="Kind" Value="ArrowBack"/>
                  <Setter TargetName="txtBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="NavigationDataTemplate">
   <iconPacks:PackIconMaterialDesign x:Name="MenuItemIcon" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12"/>

   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="Home">
         <Setter TargetName="MenuItemIcon" Property="Kind" Value="Home"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="Email">
         <Setter TargetName="MenuItemIcon" Property="Kind" Value="Email"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="Cloud">
         <Setter TargetName="MenuItemIcon" Property="Kind" Value="Cloud"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="Collapse">
         <Setter TargetName="MenuItemIcon" Property="Kind" Value="Mail"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="NavigationDataTemplate1">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <iconPacks:PackIconMaterialDesign x:Name="MenuItemIcon" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
   </StackPanel>
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="Home">
         <Setter TargetName="MenuItemIcon" Property="Kind" Value="Home"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="Email">
         <Setter TargetName="MenuItemIcon" Property="Kind" Value="Email"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="Cloud">
         <Setter TargetName="MenuItemIcon" Property="Kind" Value="Cloud"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

The attached property class as below:

```
public class IsOpenInfo
{
   public static bool GetIsOpen(DependencyObject obj)
   {
      return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsOpenProperty);
   }

   public static void SetIsOpen(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
   {
      obj.SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value);
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(IsOpenInfo), new PropertyMetadata(true));
}
```

I am clueless why the attached property not updating when `IsChecked` property is changed  and style triggers not working?
Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Anyone guide me to handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style is defined with `TargetType` set to `ListBox`, the triggers will resolve the value of your custom `local:IsOpenInfo.IsOpen` property for the `ListBox` instance that your style is applied to.

However, the `ToggleButton` is defined inside the `ControlTemplate` of the `ListBox`. Its `IsChecked` binding will not automatically set the value of the attached property on its *templated parent* control. It will be set on the `ToggleButton` itself. So practically, you are setting the value on the `ToggleButton`, but you are checking it on the `ListBox` in the style, so you are operating on different values.

You can make it work by explicitly binding to the `TemplatedParent`, which is a `ListBox` instance. Both the style and the toggle button will resolve the attached property value for the same `ListBox` instance.

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding (local:IsOpenInfo.IsOpen), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
              Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonstyle}"
              Foreground="White"/>
```

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to make toggle button also behave like listitem because the toggle is working only when I press on the image if I press on the blue background it is not toggled as expected

Comment: @NAGASREE The `ToggelButton` does not have a background, so in the control template setting the `Background` of the `StackPanel` to `Transparent` should work: `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">`. If you want the same button effects as for the list box items, you will have to adapt the control template of the `ToggleButton` accordingly.